# Sync photo albums between Mac and iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos, photos.app, photo-stream

I am having this problem already a few months now and I wonder why there isn't any solution for it because it belongs to the basics of photos. I am talking about photo albums. And by a photo album I don't mean my whole photo library, I mean albums which I create on my iPhone with titles like New York, Los Angeles or Europe Trip which contain only selected photos I took. That's a photo album. So, I can have many photo albums within my photo library.

Apple simply doesn't support to sync those photo albums. I do have an Apple MacBook Pro and sync my photos between the iPhone and the MacBook with the Photos app provided by Apple. However, whenever I do this, I just have all the photos on my MacBook but not the albums. That is so annyoing because it just doesn't make sense to me... Also, I want to have this working in both directions.

Do you guys know if this is possible and if yes, how?

Comment: What is the status on web ? Then we can identify which device is at fault. It is expected to sync them AFAIR though I can’t test it at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic ways to do this. You can use iCloud for storing pictures and then also use it for pictures on your Mac.

The other way is when you connect your phone to your Mac with a lightning cable. Then you can go in iTunes and go to the phone setting and sync options where it will ask you what do you want to sync there would be multiple tabs pictures would be one of them. (*You will have to turn off iCloud for this.*)

If you are on macOS Catalina then you can connect your phone go to Finder. Go to your phone, and change tabs to pictures and check the sync option. Then go back to the general tab and then click sync, it will take some time but you should be able to do it.

[This video from Apple should help you](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELpw1jxFxnE)